# Bootstrap-Notify in Grails 2.5

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap-3, notifications

Anyone with the know-how on using the [Boostrap Notify plugin](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/) with a Grails application?

Here is what I did. After adding the bootstrap-notify.js to assets/javascripts, and adding this line to main.gsp:

```
<asset:javascript src="bootstrap-notify.js" />
```

I tried to display a notification with this line which I added to a g:javascript clause in a gsp page:

```
$.notify("Hello World");
```

thinking a notification would show up upon page load, but nothing displays. If someone is using it successfully where a notification is displayed on demand it would be greatly appreciated to see how.

Comment: did you check your console for an error?

Comment: Just did. It says: Uncaught TypeError: $.notify is not a function ; is this a show stopper? But how else to use it then? Was following the docs of the API.

Comment: Did you check in the generated HTML that the libraries are being included? Is jquery being included before bootstrap? In any case, this is a javascript/bootstrap question, little relation with grails.

Comment: Yes, all other libraries are included in the HTML it works fine with all other sorts of plugins. You are right that this is a javascript/bootstrap question, this is why I asked for a know-how rather than claiming a bug. Thanks for your input.